# scroll position at the same after another page loaded

Tags: jquery

I want to get scroll position at same when the user clicks any menu of navigation bar. When menu is clicked the window is refreshed! I think this is different than window refresh.

How could I get the scroll position at same when window is refreshed?

---

My site implement is likely to this http://jsfiddle.net/JUKBP/1/ and my scroll position is at something mid that is green div `hidden` condition

Comment: What did you try till now? Show us some code and preferably a fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this. (javascript solution).

Note: I am using https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie for cookie

get Window ScrollTop value (you can use jQuery for easy). eg: `$(window).scrollTop()`
Save value on cookie.
eg:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  var top = $(window).scrollTop();
  $.cookie('widowtop', top);
});
```

you can read that value from cookie, where you want to scroll page at beginning. 
and use jQuery (for easy) to set window scroll at document.ready event.

eg: on your document

```
$(function(){
    var top = $.cookie('widowtop');
    $(window).scrollTop(top);
});
```

Comment: I tried your code but it's working only when window is refreshed but no luck with menu click

Comment: My site implement is likely to this http://jsfiddle.net/JUKBP/1/ and my scroll position is at something mid that is green div hidden condition

Comment: I am sure when you click the menu, you navigate to different page. Which means, you have to put 2nd code (in above example) in every page.

Comment: I'm using joomla template and I placed your code in index.php then it loads on all page

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
  function onAjaxCall(){  
    scrollTop=$(document).scrollTop();        
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function(data){
      //action with data
      $(document).scrollTop(scrollTop);
    },
    dataType: dataType
    });
  }
```

Comment: Tried this too but working only on refresh of window not with menu click.

Comment: where is ur code?? so I can check... your fiddle does not contain any menu click event.

Comment: I'm implement locally. anyway you can check in your own website first scroll to mid and click any menu you have